# DFT Graph has too many oscillations?

Tags: dft

I'm very new to the DFT, and am working on it for a HS project.
I've taken the DFT of my instrument playing (the original waveform looking like this: [image: original data]

But after plotting the DFT onto Desmos, I get a graph which looks like the following:
[image: DFT result]

Is this normal?

Comment: DFT is periodic as in your case

Comment: It looks like you are plotting the real part, not the magnitude or level. The output of the DFT is a complex number.